# Deleted a row in sysobjects in sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I was querying tables in sysobjects when I accidentally pressed "D", triggering the delete row option in the results pane. For some reason, I can still query the table using the select statement but when I use the lookup table option (F7), the table is not in the list. I tried to query sysobjects to retrieve all user tables but the table is not there but the columns/fields for that table can still be queried in syscolumns in which the where clause I used is "where object_name(id) = 'table_name'".

I also tried creating the table again but it just shows an error "mismatch found between the name and id descriptor hash table for table."

I'm considering to run the drop statement but it may cause more errors on the database.
Is there anyway to retrieve the table? I still have the records for the table and also the dll for it to be created.

I'm new to Sybase. The program I'm running is Sybase Central v6.0

Comment: if you still have all the data for the sysobjects row you could try inserting the row of data back into sysobjects, otherwise your best bet is going to be a) recovering from a backup or b) deleting all associated rows from other tables (syscolumns, sysindexes, syspartitions, etc, etc, etc, etc .... and then bouncing the dataserver - to clear memory) ... then cross your fingers

Comment: the bigger issue you need to address ... who enabled `allow updates to system tables` and *why*?  at some point you need to disable this feature otherwise you'll continue to shoot yourself in the foot